# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character or IncompatibleClassChangeError depending on Tomcat 7 version

Tags: java

I am facing those problems. Firstly using Tomcat 7.0.73 I got the following error

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status does not implement the requested interface javax.ws.rs.core.Response$StatusType
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.getStatus(ContainerResponse.java:599)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.commitWrite(ContainerResponse.java:157)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.write(ContainerResponse.java:134)
```

Then I added javax to the BuilthPath and the console gives me this other error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:467)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:667)
```

As I could see this is a bug of Tomcat last versions when trying to reach an URL with characters as `%`, `&`...

So then I downgrade, and try other versions as Tomcat8, Tomcat 7.47 ... but in those one I get the first error `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError`

I've been reading a lot a trying to do different things but still I cannot access to my Java classes (because of those errors), though the html and js files are working fine in the WEB-INF folder.

Any help?, thanks

Comment: Hi @JarrodRoberson, i don't think is a duplicate. This question is about jersey api and javax servlet. This has nothing to do with the question that you pointed.

Comment: this could be a question and solution but it didn't help to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890438/how-to-add-jsr-311-dependency-for-jersey-jax-rs-maven-project