# How do you include JAX-RS with Jersey in Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jersey

I'm following a tutorial on Vogella on how to work with JAX-RS to create RESTful web applications.

The trouble for me is that I am not able to import the dependencies through Maven. Is it possible?

When I try finding `jsr311` or `javax.ws.rs` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18139088/1675976), Maven doesn't seem to know it exists.

[image: Maven Dependency JSR]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are satrting your project from scratch, it would be better to let maven generate your project for your using one of the *Maven Archetypes* that *Jersey* provides (More in the [Jersey getting-started page](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html)) then you can easilly add the eclipse nature to the generated project using below command:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

*Choose your suitable Web Tool version*, then import that project into your *Eclipse IDE*.
This method, will leave you out of poviding any dependencies related to *Jersey* as those are already mentioned in the archetype descriptor.

Otherwise, if you are already working on a project and you want to add the RESTful features (which assume is not true since you mentioned that you are following a tutorial), you will have to provide dependencies to *Jersey* yourself. All dependencies can be found [in Maven Central Repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey) but you would only need the `jersey-server` one:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
```

As @Gimby stated, there is absolutely no sense in declareing the `jsr311-api` alone, only if you are intending to provide a JSR implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890438/how-to-add-jsr-311-dependency-for-jersey-jax-rs-maven-project).

Solved the problem by manually adding the dependency under `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You need a proper JAX-RS implementation such as Jersey or RestEASY in your Maven dependencies; that will transitively also provide the API dependency. Now you can compile, but you still can't actually run or deploy anything. This thread has more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476820/jax-rs-in-relation-to-jersey-and-jsrs

Comment: Can Jersey be added through Maven somehow?

Comment: Hello, if you google "jersey maven" the first hit is a link to the very complete online Jersey manual.

Answer (score 0):

**please try as following:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

foun it on : (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes/project/2.22.1)
it will work inchalahh ;D

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
```